# Angular проекты с нуля

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5, node-modules

Работаю в готовом проекте где используется angular (front) и nodeJs (backend). Хотел бы сделать свой такой проект с нуля. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как сделать? Может есть ресурсы, книги или другие источники, где описано как с нуля, на примерах, всё это поднять (back и front) ?

Answer (score 1):

Как написать backend на ноде документации на `express` бооолее чем достаточно, по 100 раз переписывать одно и то-же нет некакого смысла. Можете прям тут в поиске забить `express` вам выдаст очень много полезной инфы с ходу.

Как поднять ангуляр, у них в официальной статье всё есть - https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Хотя если вы не знакомы с экосистемой ангуляра, я бы для начала посоветывал начать с чего нибудь попроще. С Vue3 или AngularJS.

Comment: Хорошо. Ну как их совместить, сделав fullstack приложение?

Comment: Вариаций прам очень много. В ангуляре есть `$http` https://angular.io/guide/http если хочеться по модному, сделай через `axios.config` https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config если хочеться заморочиться то можно сделать прям обёртку через свой middleware и использовать socket.io

Comment: Понятно. А есть ли конкретный пример, как их совмещать или как всё это организовать? Пошагово я имею виду. Например, развернули Angular (front), NodeJS (back), подключили БД (например PostgreSQL), создали первое приложение, запустили фронт и бэк и т.п.

Comment: Ну думаю стоит поискать готовые border-plate на гитхабе. https://github.com/vyakymenko/angular-express или https://github.com/gtsopour/angular-cli-express-starter Вообщ в чём частая беда таких проектов, в том что каких-то готовых решений нету, скольо людей, столько мнений. Как правило такие проекты собираються ручками и в каждой комманде по свойму.